# The ad unit ID must be set on InterstitialAd before loadAd is called

Tags: java

Below is the code. I received an error message that the ad unit ID must be set on InterstitialAd before loadAd is called.

Android studio appointed error code that is mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
what is wrong in the below code?

MainActivity .java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    String Interstitial_id = MyApplication.Interstitial_ad_unit_id;

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(Interstitial_id);
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
                  /*   if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                         webView.goBack();
                     } else { */
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                finish();
            }
        });
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

activity_main.xlm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">kidsyube</string>


    <!-- 테스트용-->
    <string name="APPLICATION_ID">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
    <string name="Interstitial_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>



</resources>



MyApplication.java



import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static String Interstitial_ad_unit_id;
    public static String APPLICATION_ID;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        //테스트용
        MyApplication.Interstitial_ad_unit_id = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        MyApplication.APPLICATION_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: yes, but I keep getting error messages....TT

Comment: TT... reminds me of **Twice TT :D** ...because we never use this... seems like Koreans use this too much... **:D**

Comment: Is this line fetching string corerctly? **String Interstitial_id = MyApplication.Interstitial_ad_unit_id;**

Comment: print logs at each step and see where it is misbehaving.

Comment: thank you for your comment and I am sorry that I did not reply your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Add Id like this at the beginning of `onCreate` (before calling
>   Ads):

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3399353667275215~87472*****");
```

> To Add in Manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3399353667275215~8747253052"/>
```

> Add `super.onAdClosed`:

```
public void onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed();
                    finish();
                }
```